# COUNT(DISTINCT Column1) for Only One Column of Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

Admittedly, I've seen this question on here a few times -- but all the answers seem to solve their problems by using a `GROUP BY` or a `WHERE`, so I was curious how to get around this if your query is getting too large where that wouldn't work.

For example, I'm writing something that uses two left joins to my main table, bringing the overlaps over into the results. As I'm still relatively new to SQL, I'm not exactly sure what's doing it -- but I know that I'm getting an extra thousand or so people when I run the counts; I'm imagining this is the case because there are duplicate IDs for each person (purposefully) in the two tables I'm joining.

All my queries populating the results I want to get for this project is using `COUNT()` or `SUM()` pending on the column. Is there a way that I can use `DISTINCT` to make only one column at a time treat my IDs only as one? Based on what I've done so far, I've noticed that whenever you set `DISTINCT` it works beyond just the one column you're trying to attribute it to. Any suggestions? It'd be very appreciated!

Here's an example of my code so far that includes duplicate IDs:

```
SELECT
     targeted.person AS "Person",
     targeted.work AS "Occu",
     (COUNT(targeted.id)) AS "Targeted",
     (COALESCE(SUM(targeted.signed="Yes"),0)) AS "Signed",
     (COALESCE(SUM(targeted.signed="Yes"),0))/COUNT(targeted.id)*100 AS "Signed %",
     (COALESCE(COUNT(question.questionid="96766"),0)) AS "Donated",
     (COALESCE(COUNT(question.questionid="96766"),0))/(COALESCE(SUM(targeted.signed="Yes"),0))*100 AS "Donated %",
     (COALESCE(SUM(question.surveyresponsename),0)) AS "Donation $",
     ROUND((COALESCE(SUM(question.surveyresponsename),0))/(COALESCE(COUNT(question.questionid="96766"),0)),2) AS "Avg Donation",
     (CASE WHEN (left(targeted.datesigned,1)="5" AND right(question.datecontacted,2)="13") THEN (COALESCE(SUM(targeted.signed="Yes"),0)) ELSE 0 END) AS "Signed This Month",
     (CASE WHEN (left(question.datecontacted,1)="5" AND right(question.datecontacted,2)="13") THEN (COALESCE(COUNT(question.questionid="96766"),0)) ELSE 0 END) AS "Donated This Month",
     (CASE WHEN question.ContactType="House Visit" THEN COUNT(question.id) ELSE 0 END) AS "At Home",
     (CASE WHEN question.ContactType="Worksite" THEN COUNT(question.id) ELSE 0 END) AS "At Work",
     (CASE WHEN (left(events.day,1)="5" AND right(events.day,2)="13") THEN COUNT(events.id) ELSE 0 END) AS "Events This Month"
      FROM targeted
       LEFT JOIN question ON targeted.id=question.id
       LEFT JOIN events ON targeted.id=events.id
      GROUP BY targeted.person, targeted.work;
```

Here are the basics of the table structures:

Targeted:

```
Field       Type            Null    Key     Default
ID          bigint(11)      YES     Primary NO
Work        varchar(255)    YES             NULL
Person      varchar(255)    YES             NULL
Signed      varchar(255)    YES             NULL
DateSigned  varchar(255)    YES             NULL
```

Question:

```
Field               Type            Null    Key     Default
ID                  bigint(11)      YES     Primary NO
QuestionID          int(11)         YES             NULL
SurveyResponseId    int(11)         YES             NULL
SurveyResponseName  varchar(255)    YES             NULL
DateContacted       varchar(255)    YES             NULL
ContactType         varchar(255)    YES             NULL
```

Events:

```
Field       Type            Null    Key     Default
ID          bigint(11)      NO      Primary NO
Day         varchar(255)    YES             NULL
EventType   varchar(255)    YES             NULL
```

And the results would are intended to look something like:

```
Person  Occu    Targeted    Signed  Signed % ...
1       Job 1   1413        765     54.14 ...
2       Job 2   111         80      72.072 ...
2       Job 3   931         715     76.7991 ...
3       Job 4   2720        1435    52.7573 ...
4       Job 5   401         218     54.364 ...
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "left joins ... not exactly sure what's doing it" <- Actually wanted to stop reading there. How about learning about left joins before using them? Also it works exactly like your title says. Why not try it out, or google for it? Also a desired result is not of much help when we don't know the data used to generate it.

Comment: Can you add the table structures to the question? Also, are you sure that you should be joining between the tables on the `id` fields?

Comment: @tombom        Not exactly sure what you're saying? I feel fairly confident about using left joins. I have researched them, and they work like filling in a Venn Diagram with all of the first set of data and the intersection of the second set. Probably wouldn't have been able to write this if I didn't Google this or test it out. Offering help usually works better than assuming that I don't know anything. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBannister Thanks! And I'm pretty sure I need to join on the ID, because that's the only primary/foreign key that match throughout the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to solve this problem is by doing the aggregation in the subqueries.  To aggregate questions and events to the right level, you need to join in the targeted table.  Then, you will not need the aggregation at the outermost level:

```
select . . .
from (select t.name, t.work,
             count(t.id) as Targeted,
             . . .
      from targets t
      group by t.name, t.work
     ) t left join
     (select t.name, t.work,
             sum(case when question_id = 96766 then 1 else 0 end) as Donated,
             . . .
      from question q join
           targeted t
           on t.id = t.id
      group by t.name, t.work
    ) q
    on t.name = q.name and t.work = q.work left join
    (select t.name, t.work,
            sum(CASE WHEN (left(events.day,1)="5" AND right(events.day,2)="13") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
               ) AS "Events This Month"
    from events e join
          targeted t
          on e.id = t.id
    ) e
    on e.name = t.name and e.work = t.work
```